# Typescript AWS Lamba: QueryString Parameters is undefined

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple lambda function written in typescript ( little to no experience)

I am trying to extract query string parameters from event object received to lambda but it tells me this error.

```
(property) APIGatewayProxyEventV2WithRequestContext<APIGatewayEventRequestContextV2>.queryStringParameters?: APIGatewayProxyEventQueryStringParameters | undefined
    'event.queryStringParameters' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
```

Here is my lambda code

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEventV2, APIGatewayProxyResultV2, APIGatewayProxyEventV2WithRequestContext, Context } from 'aws-lambda';



const region = process.env.AWS_REGION


export async function handler(
    event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> {


    console.log('event ', event);

    const token = event.queryStringParameters.token 
    const Url = event.queryStringParameters.Url
```

const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message. //If I get event from aws service similar error.

```
    if (token) {
        await sendApproval(event.queryStringParameters)
        return {
            statusCode: 301,
            headers: {
                Location: Url,
            }
        };

    } else {
        return {
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Oops Approval was not sent successfully' }),
            statusCode: 502,
        };
    }

}
```

IN a similar fashion if there is an event from aws services which required me to extract it. It has a similar kind of error where Records does not exist   `const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message`

In order to solve this I am fixing it with a `!` operator.

```
const token = event.queryStringParameters!.Token
    const Url = event.queryStringParameters!.Url
```

Is this the only to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The '@types/aws-lambda' package is trying to warn you that `queryStringParameters` attribute may not exist on the incoming event.

By using the `!`, you are telling the TypeScript compiler that the type definition is wrong and that the `queryStringParameters` will never be `undefined`.

A better way to write the code would be to accept that the `queryStringParameters` may be `undefined` and add some code to handle it, avoiding an unexpected, and difficult to diagnose, error.

```
const token = event.queryStringParameters?.token
if (!token) {
    throw new Error("The token query string parameter was not found on the request!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of handling this

1. You can check if event.queryStringParameters is defined before attempting to access the field.
2. You can use the object index accessor like `constant token = event.queryStringParameters[‘Token’]`
3. You can disable strict mode in your tsconfig (not recommended)